# What's the difference for the three ways to convert string to date

Tags: postgresql

I have three ways to convert a string to date:

```
1. select date '2021-08-24'
2. select '2021-08-24'::date
3. select to_date('2021-08-24')
```

I would ask what's the difference between them and which one is preferred, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first is a ANSI SQL compliant date literal which should work on any database that supports the ANSI SQL standard (for date or timestamp literals).  I prefer this format because it is portable - at least across the DBMS products I use.

The second is Postgres specific way to cast a string value to a date.

The third is invalid in Postgres. Although Postgres supports a function named `to_date()` it requires at least two arguments: the string to be converted and a format mask that specifies how the input string is structured. `to_date('2021-08-24', 'yyyy-mm-dd')` would be valid. It is a non-standard function though (but e.g. Oracle also supports it)

Comment: thanks @a-horse-with-no-name for the great answer!